# Changing property when clicked - Android

Tags: android

I have 15 ImageView where I assign a 'shape' as background. What I want to achieved is when I click these ImageViews, the shape's stoke property will change from 0dp to 4dp. But when I clicked the ImageView again, it will turn back to 0dp. I also want to limit the number of ImageView that can be clicked. For example, If I have clicked 8 ImageView already (that changes their stroke property from 0dp to 4dp), it won't allow me to change others ImageView stroke property anymore, unless I clicked one ImageView (that will removed it's 2dp stroke and will reset it to 0dp).

This is the code I have so far. Which allows me to click the ImageViews and change their stroke property to 4dp. I am googling/stackoverflow for solutions but can't find one. Hope you can help me.

```
private int[] colors = {R.color.filter_dark_blue, R.color.filter_rouge, R.color.filter_blue, R.color.filter_burgundy,
        R.color.filter_turquoise, R.color.filter_navy, R.color.filter_green, R.color.filter_black,
        R.color.filter_yellow, R.color.filter_charcoal, R.color.filter_orange, R.color.filter_grey, 
        R.color.filter_warm_red, R.color.filter_white, R.color.filter_pink};

private ImageView[] color = new ImageView[colors.length];

for (int i = 0 ; i < color.length ; i++) {
        color[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(ivCirclesId[i]);
        final GradientDrawable ivCircleOnClick = (GradientDrawable) color[i].getBackground();
        color[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                ivCircleOnClick.setStroke(4, Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Whats the need of google here? To implement it as simple as describing it. add logic to check state and set stroke accordingly in onClikcListener.

Comment: Sorry @ShailendraSinghRajawat. I am just starting to Android and Java at the same time. I usually don't have an idea and want to learn through the process. If I can't solve the problem or can't find solutions on web anymore, that's when I asked question. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is snippet, 
some quick ideas ...

1- use the setTag(Object) and getTag() to set 0/1 value, as clicked flag

```
color[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(ivCirclesId[i]);
final GradientDrawable ivCircleOnClick = (GradientDrawable) color[i].getBackground();
//add this
color[i].setTag("0");//not clicked when created.
```

2- use global variable as counter for total clicked images, to control the limit 8 issue, if its set to 4 then increment the counter ++counter, if reset to 0, decrement the counter --counter, and change setTag()

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getTag().toString().equals("1")){
        --clicked;
        v.setTag("0");
        ivCircleOnClick.setStroke(0, Color.WHITE);
    }else{
        if(clicked >= 8){
        //max limit reached, nothing to do... add toast if you want ...
        return;
        }
        ++clicked;
        v.setTag("1");
        ivCircleOnClick.setStroke(4, Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```